# I assistance with with div tags and css with adding anchor tags

Tags: html, css, anchor

I made a box with `<div class="box"></div>` then I styled it in css with `.box {}` but I want to make it so when I click the box, it brings me to another page. Here is my current code.

```css
.box18 {
    width: 240px; height: 230px;
    outline: 5px solid black;
    position: absolute; top: 450px; right: 140px;
    background-image: url(wfc.jpg);
    background-position: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="box18" title="Credit: Hasbro/Takara"></div>
```

I tried to add an anchor tag within the div or within the css styling but it didnt work and made the text dissapear.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried and describe what 'didnt work' means. This link should help you put code into your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap your div in an anchor tag.

```css
.box18 {
    width: 240px; height: 230px;
    outline: 5px solid black;
    position: absolute; top: 450px; right: 140px;
    background-image: url(wfc.jpg);
    background-position: top;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
  <div class="box18" title="Credit: Hasbro/Takara"></div>
</a>
```